# Changing background images on click

Tags: html, css, displaytag

I have a table with a header that is sorted using the Display tag library.

When a header is clicked, I want to remove a background image from the other headers and display an "Up Arrow" image. When the same header is clicked again, I want a "Down Arrow" image to be displayed.

This is the CSS I'm using to do it right now.

CSS

```
th {
    height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
}

th.sortable a:ACTIVE {
    background: url("../images/integration/downArrow.gif") no-repeat 30%;
} 

th.order1 {
    background: url("../images/integration/upArrow.gif") no-repeat 30%;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a bit more context here. The code you've included - does it work? Why is it not achieving your goal? Rather than telling us "I want this, This should do such-and-such", *ask us a question* so we can help you!

Comment: Could you give us a demo of the code working as it? JSfiddle, CodePen, or a snippet? I could give you a solution in theory, but need the code to provide a working solution.

Comment: Guys, please take it easy. I am using Display tag library which is taking care of my sorting and also the images are there too. But what I am trying to achieve is to initially show an image only on on of the headers. You won't get the code because it is done using Display tag.

Comment: Hmm. You can add the Display tag library to a JSfiddle, CodePen, or a snippet. You just need to copy and paste your HTML code. Also, for your question, you might need JS. Are you willing to use it?

Comment: This is my first time dong it. I want some ideas how to achieve it. JS I didn't think about it. Previously it was done using EL but now Display tag is taking care of most of the stuff. I got stuck only in this part.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with what you are trying to achieve? I've included the `displaytag` tag so that people who know what that is can find this question, but I still feel this question could be a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, and I am extremely sorry those who are still trying to understand the question. Run my solution and you will not only get the question also the answer. I just needed to configure order1 and order2 in my CSS.

```
th.order1 {
background: url("../images/integration/upArrow.gif") no-repeat 30%;
} 

th.order2 {
background: url("../images/integration/downArrow.gif") no-repeat 30%;
}
```